# Rails Passing param from form to persist sorting order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I trying to pass a hidden param in my form that maintains the sort order of my list. I am able to pass the query param without a problem but cannot seem to pass in a custom param to the controller. I am not sure how to do this correctly and have tried using `f. hidden_param` with no success.

The form is hooked up to stimulus reflex and submits with every key press.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<%= form_with url: x_path, method: :get do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :query, value: params[:query] %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: What issue are you facing, we understand you were not successful in implementing it but did you get any error like unpermitted parameter or unknown attribute?

Comment: The param just doesn't get passed to the controller. I don't get any errors whatsoever. For example if I add `<%= f.hidden_field :sort, value: your_value_asc_or_desc %>` to the form if I go in to the controller `params[:query].present?` works but `params[:sort].present?` doesn't

Comment: Turns out it was a problem with Stimulus reflex. I refactored the js code and it works now

Answer (score 0):

Just try this .....

```
<%= f.hidden_field :sort, value: your_value_asc_or_desc %>
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a form in the first place and you can't actually pass "hidden parameters" in a GET request as there is no request body.

In GET the only thing the server recieves is the request URI and any headers sent by the client (such as cookies). If you want to add parameters to a GET request just add them to the query string:

```
<%= link_to 'Link text', x_path(query: { foo: 'bar' }) %>
```

The result is identical to if you created a form with hidden inputs. On the controller side there is difference between request body and query string parameters. Both are added to the `params` hash.